# Do ferry flights to the US that are not ADS-B Out equipped require a special ferry permit from 1 Jan 2020?

Tags: faa-regulations, ads-b, ferry-flight

The aircraft is not compliant with ADS-B Out DO 260B and will be parked in Arizona after return. Can this aircraft fly to the State for ferry flight only to US without ADS-B Out DO 260B? Should I apply to FAA about ferry special permit in advance?

Comment: This depends on what "State" is (more specifically, your route of flight)... You can also make the request to the controlling ATC to transit the airspace at least 1 hour prior to the operation if you do not have ADS-B, if it is a long flight, this may be a lot of phone calls. I don't believe a ferry permit is required (unless for other reasons).

Comment: You probably solved this by now, but if you keep the aircraft away from Class B (30 NM) and below 10,000 MSL, you don't have to have ADS-B.